# Can't boot ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on AsRock z77 extreme 4

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, live-usb, livedvd

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I tried to boot Ubuntu from DVD and from USB (which was 
created with unetbootin) both in UEFI and in AHCI mode (which is AsRock's BIOS mode I think), but none of the four options worked for me: there is always a blinking console, that freezes after some seconds and I have to turn off the computer... With the DVD I first get to the screen on this picture:

[image: Ubuntu Boot Image]

... and then the thing with the console. I have got one HDD with three partitions and Windows 7 installed.

my specs:

- Asrock z77 extreme 4 motherboard
- Intel Core i7 3770k
- Nvidia Geforce Gtx 770
- 8 Gb RAM
- 1 TB HDD

My UEFI looks like this:

[image: UEFI Boot Image]

Comment: @Fabby, Say please, what a reason to edit original user orthography?

Comment: @swift: better questions.  I can sometimes see what the mother tongue is of someone just by looking at the way they write English.  And forgetting to use the verb "To be" is very Russian!  ;-)  Sometimes it's *extremely hard* to even *understand* the question unless you actually know the person's mother tongue.

Comment: You do not right. There exist separate StackExchange blog for an exercised their English users. You replaced user's "all four options didn't work" to "none of all ... worked". Fast view it is looking alike simply "worked" and just breaks user's hope for a simple little bit. And maybe some possible dialogue. You're understand me?

Comment: "mother tongue" ... you're vulgar, Fabby

Comment: [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: about "mother tongue": this is just a different word for "native language", I don't think that this is meant to be vulgar. [I do not want to comment on any other stated things, just wanted to mention this...]

Comment: You could try to disable UEFI boot and then try to boot Ubuntu (just to see if it works - you might not want to install it with UEFI disabled). @Kai [the Kai who posted the question]: cool name :-D

Comment: Do you have any drive including DVD plugged into the ASmedia ports, those always cause issues.

Comment: I know the name is pretty cool :D where can I disable the UEFI mode? Yes I have the DVD and the HDD plugged into it so I try this out tomorrow and I comment if it worked or not

Comment: I am not sure where, but it might be in 'Advanced' or 'Boot'. Do you have another operating system installed on the same computer? (This other OS might need UEFI enabled to boot, so you might need to re-enable UEFI after trying ubuntu)

Comment: Oh, and please try oldfred's solution before, it is more likely to work since you already tried AHCI mode.

Comment: I have switched the DVD and HDD to the normal ports and now it works for me :D Correct me if I am wrong but I think I can't disable the UEFI mode because I don't find the option for that I only can select wether to boot in UEFI mode or in AHCI mode. I have got Windows 7 installed but I can't remember in which mode I installed it so can anybody say me how to find that out? Or do I have to do the installation with trial and error because I want to keep Windows and to be able to select on start which OS I want to boot.

Comment: Well, if Ubuntu boots in UEFI mode I guess that you should install it in UEFI mode. I've got UEFI on my Notebook, too and the only thing I had to do after installing Ubuntu next to Windows 7 was to make the Ubuntu entry in the "Boot"-Tab in the UEFI menu the first entry. (Now GRUB is shown at startup and I can also choose Windows 7 from the menu.) (To check whether Windows 7 is installed in (U)EFI mode: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29504-bios-mode-see-if-windows-boot-uefi-legacy-mode.html (I'd recommend Option 3))

Comment: So I found out that Windows was installed in BIOS mode so I installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode too and everything is working fine for me so thanks to all who helped me :D

Comment: Great to hear !